# Less than or equal to for a datetime field in REST API search query

Tags: 2013, 2010

I am trying to make a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) API call to fetch the list of pages published before a given date and time:

```
//_api/search/query?querytext='Path:http:sharepointpath owstaxIdTaxKeyword:81394a-cedb-4c19
AND
 (StoryDate<=2016-12-19)'&rowlimit=5& selectproperties='Title'&enablequeryrules=false
```

The StoryDate has values like `2015-11-19T08:00:00Z`.

I also tried `StoryDate<2016-12-19T08:00:00Z`, which didn't work. Whereas `StoryDate:2016-12-19T08:00:00Z` works.

Now the problem is how do I do a `less than or equal to` in this case given that the values I have are in date format?

Comment: try using the `lt` (less-than) operator instead of `<`

Comment: yeah i tried that too
storydate lt 2016-12-19

Comment: `1900-01-01T00:00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the field name you are using is defined in the Managed Properties in the Search Schema...

Comment: thanks 
I was using the internal column name.
 When I used the managed properties name it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

try using the below query:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('StoryDate')/Items?$filter=Created leq '11/24/2015'
```

Found this amazing tool for Search Queries : https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Comment: can i add filter for api search query?

Comment: Is there `leq`??I know `Lt`,`Le`,`Eq`,`Ne`

Comment: **OP**'s question is regarding search API (`_api/search/query?querytext`) not regarding List (`/_api/web/lists`)